# Bootstrap 5 Navbar dropdown doesn't behave like the dropdown in the documentation

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am trying to use Bootstrap 5 to create a dropdown but for some reason, the dropdown I have doesn't behave like the dropdown in the [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navbar/#how-it-works). The dropdown I have is supposed to open and close when it is clicked on but for some reason it just remains open even without being clicked on.

```css
#navbar-color {
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%28255, 255, 255, 1%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.dropdown-menu { 
    display: block;
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>

<!-- <meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." /> -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/test-dropdown.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/login-modal.css"> -->
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-3 sticky-top" id="navbar-color">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html">
          <img src="./src/img/logo-topnav.png" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
        </a>

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
        <button
          type="button"
          class="navbar-toggler"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navmenu"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
        </button>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_home_object">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/about.html" class="nav-link text-white" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" id="nav_about_object">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button"  aria-expanded="false" id="nav_service_object">
          Services
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li> -->
          <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-capitalize text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
          
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/contact.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_contact_object">Contact</a></li>

        
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
        <!-- <script>
          let isTouch = false;

          document.addEventListener("touchstart", (event) => {
            isTouch = true;
          });
          
          // Get the dropdown element
          let serviceNavElement = document.getElementById("nav_service_object");
          
          // Handle hover behavior on desktop
          serviceNavElement.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
            if (isTouch) {
              return;
            }
            serviceNavElement.href = "/Bootstrap-/services.html";
          });
          
          serviceNavElement.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
            if (isTouch) {
              return;
            }
            serviceNavElement.href = "#";
          });
          
          // Handle click behavior on mobile
          serviceNavElement.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            if (isTouch) {
              event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default link behavior
              let dropdownMenu = this.parentElement.querySelector(".dropdown-menu");
              if (dropdownMenu) {
                dropdownMenu.classList.toggle("show");
                // Close dropdown when clicking outside
                serviceNavElement.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                  if (!dropdownMenu.contains(event.target)) {
                    dropdownMenu.classList.remove("show");
                  }
                });
              }
            }
          });   
        </script> -->
       
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
      </div>
    
    </nav>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->

  
  </body>
</html>
```

This is a codepen.io link to the code:https://codepen.io/PatriotsForLife/pen/NWeRqLZ

Comment: Some of the links you provided are local, which means nobody can access them except yourself. We can only help you fix the issue if you provide a way for anyone else to repro and debug it. I suggest using codesandbox.io as it allows creating an online node-like environment. Make sure the issue is reproduced in the sandbox.

Comment: @tao thank you this is a link to codepen.io https://codepen.io/PatriotsForLife/pen/NWeRqLZ

Comment: As far as I can see, it does not reproduce the described bug. The dropdown does not open and it does not remain open. Most likely, that's because you haven't loaded Bootstrap's JS. Also, your markup (HTML) still contains links to relative files (e.g: `../css/test-dropdown.css`), which do not exist on codepen. Remove those links and add the contents of those files in the CSS editor. Make sure the pen behaves the same as the one you have on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#navbar-color {
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.dropdown-toggle {
  color: #fff !important;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%28255, 255, 255, 1%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu { 
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/test-dropdown.css" />
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-3 sticky-top" id="navbar-color">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html">
          <img src="./src/img/logo-topnav.png" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
        </a>

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
        <button
          type="button"
          class="navbar-toggler"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navmenu"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
        </button>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_home_object">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/about.html" class="nav-link text-white" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" id="nav_about_object">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          Services
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-capitalize text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
          
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/contact.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_contact_object">Contact</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
     
      </div>
    
    </nav>
```

change this type of code so its work

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Services
</a> 

css style

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu { 
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
}
```